# .post() is working under IE and Chrome but not under Firefox

Tags: firefox, jquery

I've got the problem with the below code. In IE and Chrome the POST vars are sent but under FF it is empty. I suspect that the selector is something that the FF does not like as if I give in an exact value and the POST vars are filled. Could you please give me a hint what am I doing wrong.

```
$.post(
"index.php?t=wlist&a=insert&ajax=1",
{pid:$(parent.pid).val(), q:$(parent.q).val()} ,
function(result){
    $("#wlist_content").load("index.php?t=wlist&a=view&ajax=1");
});
```

The elements which values are needed:

```
<input type="hidden" id="pid" name="id" value="[:ID:]" />
<input type="text" id="q" name="q" value="1">db</input>
```

Comment: What's in `parent.pid` ? Does it contain the # ?

Comment: Why are you sending the request twice ?

Comment: parent.pid is the locator of input id=pid. I'm nor sending the request twice. The first request updates a table with new values the second is updating the screen from the db. In this way I'm displaying the same exact values that are in the updated DB. And as I mentioned it works in Chrome and IE without a problem.

Comment: http://kepfeltoltes.hu/121023/chrome_ff_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png HEre is my problem visualized. As you might see the post data in FF is empty however the form data which is the POST equivalent in chrome is filled up with the correct values.

Comment: Can you build a minimal online example demonstrating the problem ? The error is probably in the code we don't see.

Comment: I'm almost entirly sure that there is no problem in the code. I have checked with the validator. In my opinion it is some compatibility issue.

Comment: I have also tried to create a fully fledged form and serialize it's values. Now seemingly the POST data is sent, but when hitting the server the $_POST array is empty :(

Comment: ok finally I have solved the issue with encapsulating the fields in a form and serializing it. However it would be nice to find a solution to this to avoid the using of the forms.
`$(".product_form").live("submit",function(){
 
 $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: 'index.php?t=wlist&a=insert&ajax=1',
  data:$(this).serialize(),
  success: function(result){
   
   $("#wlist_content").load("index.php?t=wlist&a=view&ajax=1");
  }
 });
 return false
});`

Comment: I wonder if there is a problem with the scope and the variable parent...